# Jquery - Conditional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that has multiple conditions, but for some reason, it is getting stuck on the first `if` statement. Does anyone see why this would be happening?

The var `k` always returns correct, but no matter what option I select, the first `if` statement is the only one that runs, despite the value of `k`.

The jQuery/JS is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var a = $("#BreedingSireUnReg"),
            b = $("#BreedingDamUnreg"),
            c = $("#BreedingDateUnreg");
        $("#BreedingOptionsUnReg").change(function () {
            var k = parseInt($("#BreedingOptionsUnReg").val());
            console.log(k);
            if (k == 2||8) {
                $(a, b, c).prop("disabled", true);
                console.log("1");
            }
            else if (k == 3||4||5||9||10||11) {
                $(a, b).prop("disabled", true);
                $(c).prop("disabled", false);
                console.log("2");
            }
            else {
                $(a, b, c).prop("disabled", false);
                console.log("3");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `8` will always be true. I believe you meant to type `if (k == 2 || k == 8)`. You always have to specify what you're checking against.

Comment: Thank you. Il give you the answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: @Mark, for your second `if`, since there is a lot of value, you can use that : `if($.inArray( k, [3,4,5,9,10,11]) !== -1)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` statement it is not right, that's the reason it is always going in `if` block:

```
if (k == 2|| k ==8)
```